# what will be the correct typing of a variable which hold `.subscribe` in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this statement in my angular 4 component methods

```
private valueChanges: any;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.valueChanges = this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
 }
```

so just want to know what will be the typing of `valueChanges` variable currently set `any`

which one is correct?

1. `valueChanes: Observable;`
2. `valueChanges: Subject;`
3. `valueChanges: Subscription;`

Comment: What does your IDE say when you look at the definition of `subscribe()` ?

Comment: It returns Subscription

Comment: why rely on IDE too much, it's a general question.

Comment: Because the IDE is the fastest way to get this information. The documentation is of course another great resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Angular Observable document](https://angular.io/guide/observables):

> The subscribe() call returns a Subscription object that has an unsubscribe() method, which you call to stop receiving notifications.